# ca not open execute file from python script due to no package metadata for streamlit

Tags: python, pyinstaller, streamlit

I wrote a script in python using streamlit 1.9.0. I tried to create an .exe file via pyinstaller but unfortunately I cannot use the exe file because of the following error.

[image]

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Conversion to exe using pyinstaller is a complicated matter. Have a [look](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/using-pyinstaller-or-similar-to-create-an-executable/902/22) on this post for example or search the web on streamlit with pyinstaller.